# Call to undefined function Illuminate\Support\random_bytes()

Tags: laravel

I receive this error message:

FatalErrorException in Str.php line 243: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Support\random_bytes()

```
  public static function randomBytes($length = 16) { 
  return random_bytes($length); 
  }
```

line 243: return random_bytes($length);

I do not understand what's wrong since a working version Laravel offline that extract online.
It does not work online though. I wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

`random_bytes` is a PHP 7 function.

I'm assuming that your offline/development stack has PHP 7 installed but not online/production.

Confirm your hosting for PHP 7 installed.